# FSharp Charting and Winforms

Tags: winforms, charts, f#

I'm having some trouble combining F# Charting with Winforms.

I have a chart showing in the form fine initially, however I can't get it to "update" when the underlying data changes based on the GUI interaction.

```
  recalcb.MouseClick
    |> Event.add (fun evArgs ->  
                                 let chart1 = DataUpdate 1 |> Chart.BoxPlotFromData 
                                 let chart2 = DataUpdate 2 |> Chart.BoxPlotFromData 
                                 let urControl = new ChartControl(chart1, Dock=DockStyle.Fill, AutoSize=true) 
                                 let lrControl = new ChartControl(chart2, Dock=DockStyle.Fill, AutoSize=true) 
                                 urpanel.Controls.Add(urControl)
                                 lrpanel.Controls.Add(lrControl) 
                                 printfn "tried to update"
                                 )
```

The data is updating correctly (i.e. chart1 and chart2 show their updated values), but the chart isn't updated in the actual form.

I tried defining the control outside the event with initial data and calling Refresh() within the event but it doesn't help.

Here is a minimal example showing the issue (ideally the graph would update on each button press):

```
[<EntryPoint>]
[<STAThread>]

let main args =
let form = new Form(Visible = true,  Width = 1310, Height = 730,FormBorderStyle=FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle,MaximizeBox = false)
let recalcb = new Button(AutoSize=true,Text="Recalculate")

form.Controls.Add(recalcb)

recalcb.MouseClick
    |> Event.add (fun evArgs -> let nm = System.Random().Next(100)
                                let urControl = new ChartControl(Chart.Point[1 .. nm], Dock=DockStyle.Fill, AutoSize=true) 
                                form.Controls.Add(urControl)
                                urControl.Refresh()
                                printfn "%A" nm 
                                )
do Application.Run(form) |> ignore
0
```

### UPDATE

Making the Chart a child of another control (i.e. Panel) and calling Clear() on the parent before readding will get this to work.

Comment: How are you showing the form?

Comment: I have the EntryPoint/STATthread, then let main args = form definitions. At the end of this Let is the Application.Run(form),0  Everything in the form seems to run ok, it's just not updating.

Comment: is the "tried to update" text printed? And can you please update the question with the code in your `main`?

Comment: Yes, it prints and I can see the data itself has been updated too when debugging. I just think I'm not using the right approach to updating the graph/control. The main function is very large.

Comment: I've added a minimal example

Comment: I'm pretty confident it is working but plotting the chart underneath the existing ones (I used the minimal example and randomised the window placement - I can see it moving around). I just need to work out how to remove the chart before redrawing.

Comment: I managed to get some sort of solution. You need to make the chart control part of another control (like panel) and call the Clear() method on the parent before readding.

Comment: It might be that you are getting the same RNG each time if you are clicking quickly.  Have you checked moving the RNG to a static variable?.